# Printing output multiple times when using dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this Python code:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

for student in students:
    for key in lloyd:
        print lloyd[key]
    for key in alice:
        print alice[key]
    for key in tyler:
        print tyler[key]
```

The output received is printing multiple values of the key data of the dictionary. Please suggest if there is anything that I can change and also, how do I print just individual key data such as just the test marks using the for loop.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for key in student: print student[key]`? Or e.g. `for key, value in student.items(): print value`? Alternatively, ditch the outer `for` loop. As it stands, you iterate over each student once for each student, i.e. three times. Please read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Also, the `print` syntax suggests that you shouldn't have tagged it 3.x.

Comment: Hello codeacademy ;) , use one loop only `for key in student : print student[key]`

Comment: I tried the same but gives a syntax error:TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict. I chose to use: for student in students:
    for key in student:
        print student[key]

Comment: `for key in student: print student[key]`, in this statement your `key` is dictionary i.e. `key` is reference of `lloyd`, `alice`, `tyler` which data type is dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

for an individual key like `'tests'` you can just use indexing  :

```
>>> for student in students:
...    print student['tests']
... 
[75.0, 90.0]
[89.0, 97.0]
[100.0, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print` statement to print student name and test marks.

```
for student in students:
    print "Name:%s\nTests:%s\n"%(student["name"], student["tests"])
```

Output:

```
Name:Lloyd
Tests:[75.0, 90.0]

Name:Alice
Tests:[89.0, 97.0]

Name:Tyler
Tests:[100.0, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve each value by the key `tests` from the student dictionary directly:

```
for student in students:
    print student["tests"]
```